# SQL Server Merge WHEN NOT MATCHED clause customizations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

When merge clause is used in SQL Server, I need to insert a row when it is not available. This is what I have tried:

```
 drop table test;
create table test (col1 int, col2 varchar(20));
insert into test values(1, 'aaa');
insert into test values(2, 'bbb');
insert into test values(3, 'ccc');
--insert into test values(4, 'eee');

merge test as target
using (SELECT * from test where col1=4) as source
on (target.col1 = source.col1)
when matched then
    update set target.col2='ddd'
when not matched by target then
    insert values (4, 'ddd');
```

This updates when upon matching but fails to insert. I have got two questions:

1. Is there a way to insert upon not matching in the above case?
2. Can I customize the not matching criteria to raise an error?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why using a JDBC connection affects your code. I would make this a stored proc, then it doesn't matter how you connect to it and your code is decoupled from the data. As far as using merge for this, read the article I posted and you decide if the risk of deadlocks is worth it or not. If it was my system I would not use merge for this. And since I didn't answer previously, no you can't use merge to raise an exception. Merge is a single statement, it is not a flow control mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merge works, it's just that your source (`SELECT * from test where col1=4`) is empty. There is no such row.

[You can raise an error using this hack.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64658/placing-an-assert-in-a-sql-server-query) For example:

```
when not matched by target then
insert values (0/0 /*ASSERT*/, NULL);
```

Comment: My intention is when the row with col1=4 is not present, insert it. I am using the source and destination table as the same and trying to do this. Can this be done or is creating the temp table is the only solution?